# Twilio Studio REST API Trigger - Status Callback

Tags: rest, twilio-studio

I'm calling a Twilio Studio via the REST API, however I don't see a way of adding the Status Callback to the API request?

Any help gratefully received :)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio have confirmed, via support, that this is not currently supported. It is on their development roadmap, but no confirmed release.